# Openstack Octavia port is down

Tags: networking, openstack

I installed Octavia service in Openstack and it worked! But in my `openstack port list` there are two related ports (amphora and loadbalancer) and LB port is down! What's wrong?

Note that my loadbalancer has active and online statuses, but I don't know why its port is down or what is its effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary: This is completely normal and how Octavia manages high availability.

Octavia uses a VIP address that can be moved between amphora (service VMs) for recovery from hypervisor failures. Inside the amphora, the port gets this VIP address assigned as a "secondary" IP.

In neutron, this address is handled with a VIP port, which reserves the VIP IP address (so we can move it to a replacement amphora VM if needed). This port is in the "DOWN" status.

To allow multiple IPs on a neutron port you have to use what neutron calls an "allowed address pair". If you look at the details of the port that is up, you will see the "allowed address pair" setting on the port that references the VIP port information and IP.

Comment: thnx, i can check it 2days later... hey john, we want to start a world wide openstack whatsapp group... if you want join us, please give me your whatsapp number... :)

Comment: Myself and the whole OpenStack octavia team are available on the OpenStack IRC channels on OFTC network. We are in the #openstack-lbaas channel.

Comment: but its private! and it's just for L.B. ...